# WebBrowser _ProgressChanged event doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, browser

I'm tried get the progress of download page in webBrowser, but it not works,the page download is complete and the event is not called. what's I'm doing wrong?

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
          webBrowser1.Navigate("http://xx.com");
  }


     private void webBrowser1_ProgressChanged(Object sender, WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            System.Text.StringBuilder messageBoxCS = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            messageBoxCS.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", "CurrentProgress", e.CurrentProgress);
            messageBoxCS.AppendLine();
            messageBoxCS.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", "MaximumProgress", e.MaximumProgress);
            messageBoxCS.AppendLine();
            MessageBox.Show(messageBoxCS.ToString(), "ProgressChanged Event");
        }
```

Example from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.progresschanged.aspx

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the url you trying to download?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check for the ProgressChanged  event on your Designer.cs file

```
this.webBrowser1.ProgressChanged += new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserProgressChangedEventHandler(this.webBrowser1_ProgressChanged);
```

Above code is working fine for me.

[image]

double click on progress change event and paste your code.